# Cannot invoke initialiser for type ‘UInt32’ with an argument list of type ‘(String.UTF8View)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Cannot work bellow line in swift 3.0 with WibmoSDK

let encoding: `CFStringEncoding = UInt32(String.Encoding.utf8)`

I have display error like

> "Cannot invoke initialiser for type ‘UInt32’ with an argument list of
>   type ‘(String.UTF8View)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
let encoding: CFStringEncoding = UInt32(String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```